# Extract message from malformed JSON GCM - Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, bundle

I am receiving a push from a C# application, the response is shown below (it is a bundle):

```
    Bundle [
    {
        google.sent_time=1472471614026,
        gcm.notification.msgid=27, 
        google.message_id=0:1472471614038882%8e7302d58e7302d5, 
        gcm.notification.aps=
        {
            "badge":1,
            "alert":
            {
                "action-loc-key":"alert action key",
                "title":"The alert title",
                "body":"The alert body"
            }
        },
        collapse_key=com.devise.push
    }
]
```

How would I go about attaining the Title and Body of the alert?

I have already tried `bundle.getString("gcm.notification.aps");`

Answer (score -1):

Yes you already try

```
bundle.getString("gcm.notification.aps");
```

this is correnct will give you full json string so you just need to parse json like this

```
String res  =bundle.getString("gcm.notification.aps");
    try {
        JSONObject mJSONObject = new JSONObject(res);
        String title =mJSONObject.getJSONObject("alert").getString("title");
        String action =mJSONObject.getJSONObject("alert").getString("action-loc-key");
        String body =mJSONObject.getJSONObject("alert").getString("body");
        Log.e(TAG, "MSG: " + title+ " :: " + action + " :: " + body );

    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```